# How to remove the message "Use PUT to insert or update list members"

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

I'm using JetPopup along with Mailchimp in a WP Theme. But while using the existing email, it showing

xxx.yyyy@gmail.com is already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list members.

I want to remove this text "Use PUT to insert or update list members". But could not found on which file should I use. Please advice

Regards

Comment: This is an error message, suppressing it is probably not a good idea. If you must do that then you'll probably have to find the correct hook that's used to generate it. Or write something in JS that will target the element containing the message and remove the desired text.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find on which file do I need to change? I mean on which file, I can found & customize this error message?